# Crear Lista personalizada en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando un app con Android Studio y Java en la cual quiero mostrar una grilla de la siguiente manera.

[image: tabla personalizada]

Es posible crear una tabla como tal?
y si es posible como puedo hacerla?

Comment: si es posible, con Table Layout

Comment: Agrega lo que has realizado o intentado por favor, verifica lo que comenta Table Layout y modifica tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: En efecto es posible, te invito a que lo intentes por si mismo primero, hay un sin fin de ejemplos en la web  https://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74. Sin embargo, si tuvieras un gran inconveniente que no puedas resolver pero que ya hayas tratado de hacerlo con gusto te podemos ayudar.

Comment: No Jorgesys, no tengo nada de código aún, pero voy a intentarlo por mi cuenta primero como dice sarai, Gracias por el Link sarai y cuando me sienta atorado, vuelvo.